# Evaluation order of operands of logical operators such as &&

Tags: c++, if-statement, operators, logical-operators

I was thinking about a situation like this :

```
if( A && B)
{
    doSomething();
}
```

Considering I am using C++, what is evaluated first ? `A` or `B` ?

And, let's imagine `A`is evaluated first, if `A` is `false`, will the `if` statement try to evaluate `B` before going out of the `if` ?

Is the comportement the same is most other programming languages ?

Comment: The behavior is the same in some other programming languages. But to find out which, you would need to investigate those individual languages.  Also note that in C++, the answer depends on whether `&&` has the built-in meaning for `bool` operands (most common), or actually calls an `operator&&` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`&&` and `||` are typically implemented as short-circuit operators. If `A` is `false`, `B` does not need to be evaluated and will (in most languages) not be. So `A` will be evaluated first and depending on its value, `B` may or may not be evaluated.